# How to install wine on ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: wine, dependencies, 17.10

im trying to install wine so i can play fortnight but when i do  sudo apt-get install --install-recommends wine-staging i get an error that says  wine-staging: depends: wine-staging-amd64 (=2.21.0~trusty) but is not going to be installed depends: wine-staging-i386 (=2.21.0~trusty) E: unable to correct problems

Answer (score 1):

These commands worked for me on a clean 17.10 install.

Based on your error, did you perhaps forget to do the `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`?

1. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
2. `wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key && sudo apt-key
   add Release.key`
3. `sudo apt update && sudo apt install winehq-stable`

See [this article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/04/how-to-add-wine-repository-ubuntu) for details.

Comment: I think you should apt-add-repository command according to the article in omgubuntu website

Comment: Feel free to post your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install the following dependencies for Wine to work on Ubuntu 17.10:

```
sudo apt install libgd3:i386
sudo apt install libgphoto2-6:i386
sudo apt install wine-stable
sudo apt install winehq-stable
```

Because my computer is 64-bit it didn't have the 32 bit/ i386 packages installed.

Comment: `apt search winehq-stable` doesn’t find anything on my Ubuntu 17.10 install. I suppose you have some PPA installed.

Answer (score 0):

**Try these commands:**

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-add-repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/'
wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key && sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt update && sudo apt install winehq-stable
```